# Where/how do I do reporting with my Augur REP?

Tags: augur

With ownership of Augur REP comes the responsibility of doing and right to do reporting monthly on outcomes of prediction market entries made on Augur.net.

Where do I go to do this reporting with my Augur REP? Do I have to store my REP somewhere special or how does the reporting system know what I own? I have looked around on app.augur.net and have not found a way to prove I own some REP and then take the assigned reporting.

Comment: Hello, could you [clarify](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/12048/edit) what you are trying to do? As it's currently written it's hard to tell what you are asking about.

Comment: @5chdn clarified, let me know if it is clear now - thanks.

Comment: @niksmac - would you please take off hold?

Comment: This is a very valid question that I and others also have.  Please do NOT close or hold this question.  You may think it's unclear if you're unfamiliar with Augur, but it is not unclear for those familiar with Augur and its very important reporting requirements for Augur rep holders.

Comment: The UI for reporting isn't done yet.  Once it is, hopefully someone will post a nice detailed answer to the question, but for now remaining unanswered is appropriate I think.  :)

Comment: Now Augur has its own stachexchange site: https://augur.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the [Augur documentation](http://docs.augur.net/#reporting):

> Once the event underlying an Augur Market occurs, the Outcome needs to be determined in order for the Market to Finalize and begin Settlement. The Outcomes of events are reported by Augur’s Decentralized Oracle, which consists of profit-motivated Reporters reporting on the Outcome of events. **Anyone who owns REP tokens may participate in the Reporting process by submitting a Designated Report or First Public Report, or by Disputing Tentative Outcomes**. Reporters whose Reports concur with consensus are financially rewarded, while those whose Reports do not concur with consensus are financially penalized.

So there are 3 options to participate in reporting:

1. **designated reporter**: chosen by the market creator, submits their answers to the market while staking REP
2. **first public reporter**: the designated reporter fails to submit an outcome, and the market moves to the open reporting phase. any user can be a first public reporter, they submit their answers while staking REP.
3. **disputing**: any user can challenge a tentative outcome by staking REP and using a dispute bond.

There should be more details in the docs on how to actually do each of these things (I'm not sure if they have actually been developed yet, so I can't answer your question as specifically as I'd like to).